# How to display various names in a text view of different intent?

Tags: java, android

I have a `multipleAutocomplete` text view in which various names are to be entered using comma token I want to display all these names in a text view of a different intent. Can anybody tell me the code?

Comment: What is a multipleAutocomplete text ? What class are you referring to ? Do you already have code to demonstrate what you are trying to do ?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do with an example?

Comment: Actually that multipleautocomplete text view is taking names of medicines so when I enter say for eg. 4 medicines I want them to be set on a the later intent which is coming after pressing a button in main activity

Comment: Save them in a SharedPref, Insert them into a DB, Make a Static Arrayof, Write them to a file? Whats stops you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I understand this right, your plan is:

Activity #1 has an EditText where you put different names like "`Ibuprofen, ASS, Dolodobendan`", then you click a button and open Activity #2, which then shows those names in a TextView.

When you click the button, somewhere in your code you have something like `Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityNumberTwo.class); startActivity(i);`right?

Instead, you do this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityNumberTwo.class);
i.putExtra("MedicineNames", multipleAutoComplete.getText().toString()); 
//multipleAutoComplete is the name of your EditText reference
startActivity(i); //or of course startActivityForResult(...);
```

Then in Activity#2 you read your names and out them to use:

```
onCreate(...){ //<-beware pseudo code
    init(); //whatever else happens here
    myTextView = findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
    myTextView.setText(getIntent.getExtra("MedicineNames");
}
```

Comment: Thanku soo much this code run for me :)